# Automating Testing of Games on iPhone

Tags: iphone, testing

Which tool is better suited to automate the testing of games on iphone?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Perfect issues is a describe in WWDC 2010 session N306 - Authomating User interface testing
There is cover 99% of necessary issues for you task.